# Algorithm to find number of combinations

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, binomial-coefficients

Let's say I have four numbers `0,1,1,3`. I want to find number of unique combination of two number. Please help me to write the algo and code of this.
I know this is more of a math question but still I have to write the code.
Please help me.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: The thing is called `Combination without repetition`. Google it..

Comment: Look at [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Answer (score 1):

From your example set `0,1,1,3`, I assume you want to allow duplicates in your input, which makes this finding the number of unique combinations harder.

Since you only want to choose unique pairs, this is much simpler than choosing unique sets of n (at least when duplicates are allowed).

The idea is to first remove all duplicates, while keeping tack of how many inputs had duplicate values.

You're answer will then be

`n C 2 + m` where `n` is the # of different elements and `m` is the # of elements with duplicates.

for `0,1,1,3`, `n = 3` and `m = 1` So you get `3 C 2 + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4`

```
(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 3)
```

The below code gives an implementation assuming your input is a vector of ints.
But you could change int to any type that has `<` defined.

```
unsigned long long unique_pairs(const std::vector<int>& elements){
    std::map<int, int> counts;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i){
        ++counts[elements[i]];
    }
    unsigned long long n = counts.size(); // # of different elements
    unsigned long long m(0);              // # of repeated elements
    for (std::map<int, int>::iterator it = counts.begin(); it != counts.end(); ++it){
        if (it->second != 1){
          ++m;
        }
    }
    return n * (n - 1) / 2 + m; // n C 2 + m
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f615741d0c2edb5)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a combination formula in it. And you should write a factorial function for it.

suppose for example you have a 4 numbers and you want number of combinations without repetition so use **4C2**

here 2 is for the number of elements you want to use in combination

4 is total number of elements that you have

so you can solve this by using **4! /(2!*(4-2)!)** ....so this calculation will give you total number of combinations without repetition

**Note : for unique combination you should have unique elements**

Comment: Isn't it **4! / 2!**, rather? **4!** gives you the number of permutations if there were 4 unique items. Then you cater for the possible permutations of the two 1s by dividng by **2!**.

Comment: He wants combination and not permutation.. and he's wants to find out total number of combinations without repetition..so given formula is used to find out the requirements of the question :)

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'm sorry. But aren't the unique combinations (0,1), (0,3), (1,1), (1,3)? Your formula works only if the pool has distinct elements.

Comment: If he want's a unique combination then he has to remove the repeated elements....if he don't do that then how it will become unique combinations :)...how will you determine that with same element (repeated ) if in first combination used first one and for second same combination, it is the next element .....so this will become illogical

Answer (score 0):

A simple pseudo-code for you is to do the thing like this:

1- `getInputs(std::vector<int> inputs)` //responsible to read inputs from the user

2- `removeDuplicates(std:vector<int> inputs)` //remove duplicates from the inputs

3- `calculateCombination(n = length(inputs))` //if you are looking for combination you should implement `n!/((n-2)!*2!)` or if you are looking for permutation you should implement `n!/(n-2)!`

Comment: OP should also add number of duplicate numbers (in original), as I understand, `{0, 1, 1}` should produce `{0, 1}` (only once) and `{1, 1}` so 2.

Comment: @Jarod42: that is correct however this is just a pseudo-code to give a general idea and because asker didn't mention any examples I leave it to him to decide what to do